# Hash function for indices greater than 64-bits?

Tags: c++, memory, hash, hashcode, tr1

From the C++ standard, the hash function std::tr1::hash computes hash values whose range is 64-bits (correct me if i'm wrong). But out of curiosity, are there any mechanisms that generate hash values with range greater than 64-bit. My question may look weird as the entire memory we use is within 64-bit range, but I would like to know how would we compute a hash value of (let's say) size 80-bit?

**EDIT :** My bad, I assumed 64-bit implementations.

Comment: You have to define your own hash number types (with 80 bits) and your own hash functions. I am not sure that C++11 gives 64 bits hashes on 32 bits implementations. Look also into [cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) like MD5 or SHA1

Comment: Yes cryptographic hash functions does the job, but aren't there any non-crypto hash functions (and also standardized) that can do the work?

Comment: You should explain why do you want large hashes... What for? Please explain why a `size_t` hash don't fit your needs!

Comment: so my key type is unsigned char array which itself is the output of a cryptographic function. And i want to avoid calling the non-crypto hash function again (which is redundant in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various hash functions in C++11 (which I suppose corresponds
to TR1) compute hash values into a `size_t`, the size of which
depends on the implementation (but will be 32 bits for a 32 bit
build, and 64 bits for a 64 bit build).  If you need a hash with
a larger size, then you'll have to calculate it yourself; you
may even have to define a larger integral type to support
calculating it.  (You can't return an 80 bit hash code in
a `size_t` if the `size_t` is only 64 bits.)